# Check if UIWebView login was successful

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, uiwebview

I am creating an app that would first make people login through a UIWebView to access the rest of the content of the app. More specifically they would be logging in through a web email server set through the company I work with. I want to know if it's first possible to do this, and if so how to confirm whether the user log in was successful?

For example I have the following code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let url = NSURL(string: "https://exchsvr02.companyname.com/owa/")
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    webView.loadRequest(request)

    // user entered valid credentials in the login screen
    // so push next page

    // invalid credentials, ask user to retry, do not push screen
}
```

Comment: In your scenario, you should have authentication API and call it. Otherwise, what UIWebView or WKWebview does is just acting as the browser, so if the login was successful, you'd be redirected to the home back (or any other page)

Comment: hey did you get an answer or find any solution for this?

Comment: @Santo no, I ended up using tokens that I would send to the users email, and then they would verify and then they would set up a username password. Not ideal, but it was for a simple app